# Load config class in App\Libraries in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, config

H Guys, 
I have custom folder in App folder call libraries in laravel 5.2 version.In that libraries folder have a error.php file. I need load my custom config file to the error.php. I have try Config::get('errorreporter.active') & config('errorreporter.active') But these to not work. any one can help me please for resolve this issue

Comment: this really isn't clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Move the file to the config folder and use the correct naming:

```
Config::get('[filename].[array_key]');
```

So if `config/error.php` has the following content:

```
<?php

return [
    'active' => true
];
```

then the correct way of calling that value would be

```
Config::get('error.active')
```

or

```
config('error.active')
```

Comment: error.php in libraries\error.php and my config file is config\errorReporter.php. inside errorreporter.php I have return ['active' => false ]; I am trying to access this config file in libraries\error.php using config('errorreporter.active') & Config::get('errorreporter.active'). But it's not work

Comment: @SanjayaPrasanna if its named `errorReporter` why are you referencing it as `errorreporter`?

Comment: @SanjayaPrasanna rename the file to `error_reporter.php` and change the config call to `config('error_reporter.active')`

Comment: @lagbox errorReporter.php is my library file. errorreporter is my config file.

Comment: @SanjayaPrasanna if the config file should be editable, make sure you can publish the file like many other packages. If not, you can just use some private properties on a class.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan This config file is editable. Also I have try to access this config file from my controller. It's work. only thing is it's not work in my custom library file.

Comment: @SanjayaPrasanna Edit your question with why you want to have it in a library, your folder structure and how you load your custom library file.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan This file I will have use, If this app have a error. This library file will insert that error details to the db. Also Email notification fire. That folder there in App\Libraries\ErrorReporter.php

Comment: @SanjayaPrasanna That is not a config file. Config files are placed in the config folder, not in a folder inside the app folder. You should really read [this documentation page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/structure) about where to put which files.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan . That is my library file. Config file there in config\error_reporter.php

Comment: Then there should be no problem. Use the name of the config file as the first part of the config name you want to acces and the key as the second. This can not go wrong, unless you get serious errors, but there is no problem with your config files.

Comment: I have used like what you said. But, It's not work. shall I share my code with you..